# Managing large number of data in holoviews/hvplot curve and scatter plots

Tags: python, plot, holoviews, hvplot

Let's say I have a large DataFrame with lots of rows and I want to do a simple line plot of the data using hvplot/holoviews.

Example:

```py
pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(1000000)]).hvplot()
```

On my machine this plot is slow to be rendered and **very slow** to navigate in with pan, zoom and so on. Is there an option to make the plot lighter to handle, kind of what `datashade` option does for multidimensional plotting?

At the moment, on my real data sampling is not an option, I want to keep all of my original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datashader is not limited to multidimensional data, so just add `datashade=True` or `rasterize=True` (which is preferred in most cases, since it lets Bokeh provide colorbars and hover information).

[image: screenshot]